# AWS EC2 Operation timeout after installing SSl

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx, ssh

I installed ssl certificate couple of days back using Let’s Encrypt.

Before, that I was easily able to login and do everything.

Now, Whenever I try to login it gives me following error

```
ssh: connect to host 172.31.XX.XX port 22: Operation timed out
```

I am using an ubuntu instance with node server and nginx. I am pretty sure this happened because I was in a rush and I copied-pasted commands before understanding what they do..

Any help would be very much appreciated. (I ran all my commands using ubuntu cli)

What I have done

- Checked my inbound and outbound rules
- Checked If I am typing the correct IP address.

I haven't changed any of these settings in a while and the last action which I performed (and could recall) was setting up ssl.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you use the EC2 console to say `sudo ufw allow ssh`? You may have omitted enabling ssh when you enabled your ufw firewall.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it will get better answers on https://askubuntu.com/ .

Comment: @O.Jones *Where in EC2 console can I type that command?

Comment: `172.31.XX.XX` is private address. So you are connecting from some bastion host? From home/work you need to use public address of your instance.

Comment: I mean the VM's console, where you can log into the ubuntu instance without benefit of ssh.

Comment: @Marcin that did it thanks :)

Comment: If you don't mind I can provide an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

`172.31.XX.XX` is a **private IP address**, accessible only from within a VPC or over VPN.

To connect from outside of AWS, a **public IP** of an instance should be used. To ensure static public IP address, an Elastic IP address can be used. Otherwise, after each restart of an instance, it will have new public IP address.